# The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

We have the production server database and Widnows Client project. Suddenly we are getting this error while querying the database.

"The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding"

How can we resolve this from Database side/ C# Windows ?

Thanks,
Velusamy

Comment: You need to provide more information to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick-and-dirty answer: set [`SqlCommand.CommandTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) to a higher value.

The long answer:

- Run the query in SSMS with "Show actual execution plan" turned on.  Check the result for index hints.
- Check your database server logs for suspicious events
- Verify that statistics are not out of date

This query shows the age of statistics:

```
SELECT  Object_Name(ind.object_id)
,       ind.name
,       STATS_DATE(ind.object_id, ind.index_id) 
FROM    SYS.INDEXES ind
```

The query optimizer uses statistics when it chooses how to execute a query.  If the statistics are old, it can make (really) bad choices.